# What is the difference between a dash and a semicolon?

Tags: differences

In English, I've seen many usages of dashes and semicolons to separate similar but not fully connected clauses. What is the difference between the two, and which is more formal to use?

Comment: Em-dashes (—) are used for parenthetical asides. Semicolons (;) are a different punctuation entirely, used to separate two complete and related sentences, or complex items in a list. En-dashes (–) are used for ranges, such as June &ndash; August. Hyphens (-) are not technically dashes. Formality has nothing to do with how you use these at all.

Comment: I'm recalling a *Murder She Wrote* episode where Jessica accurately fingered the person who actually wrote a note that was purportedly from an uneducated individual since the note contained a correct use of the semicolon, and, as Ms Fletcher said, even most college-educated people do not know how to use a semicolon correctly (or something along those lines).

Comment: dashes that are closer together normally mean that there is an emphasizing fact or long pause, kind of like a period.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They can be used in similar instances, but the em dash (long dash) is more versatile. A semicolon is more formal, and you generally don't see it written in casual writing (emails, text messages, these forums). Also, you can never follow a semicolon with an incomplete phrase. It must only precede a complete clause (that can be a standalone sentence). You have more flexibility to do this with the em dash. See example below.

Example:
I left work late today -- it was almost nine when I got home. (CORRECT)
I left work late today -- around 9pm. (CORRECT)
I left work late today; it was almost nine when I got home. (CORRECT)
I left work late today; around 9pm. (INCORRECT)

Answer (score -2):

Very inexperienced writers often tend to write run-on sentences with commas separating the phrases for line after line, but sometimes you really do want to tie two separate sentences together like that. This is what the semicolon is for.

If you want to separate two phrases with a comma, but they are actually both perfectly good sentences on their own, then use a semicolon.